Is there a way to persist gw.api.util.LocationUtil.addRequestScopedWarningMessage() on a pcf until page navigation out in Guidewire ClaimCenter?
This class method is helpful for bubbling up warning messages to the user regardless of location.
I want to persist this warning message past a page reload and wonder if there is an out of box way to do it.
ex: user updates info on a claim and I want to display a warning message from a triggered rule set after the transaction is completed.
If not, what is the convention to have a generic warning message handler that can display banners to the user? I would prefer to not have to tie core business login in the pcf directly.
I tried the gw.api.util.LocationUtil.addRequestScopedWarningMessage("displayed text") and it does not persist past a transaction. Options would be to put it in the pcf ex: afterCommit() or a page entity that displays when populated. I really don't want to do this since it's not generic.

InsuranceSuite is a JEE based application and utilizes the HTTPSerletRequest for UI queries.  HTTPServletRequest has a 'session' which stores various elements related to the users session server side.  Guidewire lets developers leverage the Servlet Session with SessionVar.
Create your SessionVar with a static new SessionVar() instruction.  Set your value with .set()  Use your value with .get().
You might look at this page in the Guidewire docs about SessionVar.  Note that a login is required to view the documentation.
https://docs.guidewire.com/is/gosu/gosu/topics/c_kj1443367.html?hl=sessionvar

This solves my use case and handles generics. I can have an empty alert banner that is visible/content based off of the SessionVar, which is set in the business logic rule.
Now, I have to figure out how to get rid of the banner after navigation; thanks for the answer.

I'll just add that if you target the PC UI behavior specifically you will bypass applying this to API requests (at least in some cases).  Be sure to consider all entry points and whether your custom behavior should apply in those cases.

A caveat to using SessionVar for alerts is that the trigger (true/false) is stored in the user's browser session and thus is unreliable. What if the user logs out or closes the browser mid-way after the alert is triggered? Another case could be when user A makes the trigger condition happen and user B navigates to the page where the alert is configured. There can be several scenarios where the alert will not be shown thereby questioning its accuracy. If the alert is irreversible in nature i.e trigger once and view everywhere, then this approach will not work. Also, what about Incognito mode?

Regardless of whether the session is managed server side or client side, session variables should remain user specific and get cleared based on the session’s lifecycle. Using them to store information that is user agnostic may not be a good idea.

The ideal way to throw a warning from a rule set would be to use the entity.reject method. As already observed by you, request scope messages do not persist on the UI if the PCF location changes or refreshes. Hence, it is not possible for the request scope warning to stick around when you commit/discard data or return from a Popup. Maybe it will be easier for you to use the Claim Validation rules and throw a reject warning. Since Claim is already a Validatable entity, you can call this method with the warning parameters.
public void reject(typekey.ValidationLevel errorLevel, java.lang.String strErrorReason, 
    typekey.ValidationLevel warningLevel, java.lang.String strWarningReason)

You can pass the warningLevel and strWarningReason while keeping other parameters null.
An unconventional way to persist a warning between pages is by using the AlertBar, Messages or VerbatimText PCF elements. You would then need to set a variable on the page that controls the visibility condition for the AlertBar. Use it with  allowDismiss=true so the user can dismiss it and it behaves like a warning/info. Of course, you need to pass this variable as a parameter from the page or PCF that produces the warning. I have seen this design being used at a couple of places in OTB code. However, this involves a lot of unnecessary customization and redundancy just to display a single warning for a single use case. So I would only use this approach if the warning is triggered before committing of a Popup and there is an absolute necessity to show it on the next screen or the TopLocation.

This is helpful however I am required to have it in banner form instead of the validation modal. I do agree with what you are saying regarding the unnecessary customization for single use cases.

I think your question could benefit from adding more details so that those who answer could make fewer assumptions. If you could add the business logic you are trying to implement, that would help greatly. I've made some assumptions below but if you add more details to your question I will update my answer accordingly.
If I understand your use case correctly, I think these are true:

You want a message displayed to a user if a claim is in a certain
state
You want this message to not be tied to a particular PCF

I see 2 ways of doing this:

Add a validation rule that will reject (with a warning message, not an error) the claim if your business logic is met. This will ensure the warning message is not tied to the PCF, but the warning message will display in a worksheet on the bottom half of the screen and the warning will be tied to the commit and not show up after the commit succeeds.
Add a new high risk indicator to the data model that shows on a claim when certain business logic is true. This is a bit more involved and includes modifying the data model as well as other steps. See the documentation below (login required). A high risk indicator will be visible after the commit that triggers the business logic and will only go away when those business logic conditions are no longer true. Be careful with high risk indicators though, you don't want to create too many (see the text I copied from the documentation). You would still need to add the indicator explicitly to the ClaimInfoBar and the ClaimStatus page, but much less than if you were trying to add an AlertBar to every PCF.

https://docs.guidewire.com/self-managed/cc/1020/config/cc/topics/c_nm1304788.html



Guidewire warning on high risk indicator usage:

IMPORTANT: Guidewire strongly recommends limiting the number of indicators used for any one line of business. Overuse of indicators lessens the overall impact to end users. Additionally, Guidewire designed the Claim Summary screen with the expectation that few, if any, claims will have more than four or five indicators. If the number of indicators per claim exceeds this expectation, Guidewire recommends that you revisit the Claim Summary screen design and determine if it needs to be modified. Otherwise, important claim information can appear farther down the screen, necessitating additional scrolling.


I am being vague on the business logic as I am trying to find out a more generic way of informing the user.
I do like the validation option as it would solve most of the requirements however I need it in banner form and non-blocking.
